# Import Excel data to OS X Calendar

Tags: calendar, ical

I'm trying to find a way to import data from an Excel file into OS X Calendar app, but I can only find articles related to iCal, which I am guessing is the iOS App.

Basically we need to import a list of birth dates into the Mac OS Calendar app, through a file exported from Excel (maybe a CSV file?) How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

iCal is just the old name for what is currently Apple's main "Calendar" application (referenced [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_(application))). They are exactly the same thing, Apple just rebranded iCal a few years ago.

That being said, there is a relatively easy (albeit lengthy) way to go about putting an Excel file into the Calendar app. Essentially you have to export the Excel document as a CSV, and then change it into an .ics format in order to get it to work. Instead of trying to repeat what I have found, [here](http://n8henrie.com/2013/05/spreadsheet-to-calendar/) is the original article (updated as of 2013) which says it much better than I can in this small space.

Comment: Correct, it's not a terribly streamlined process, which is why I made that post. The difficult part is making sure the headers are exact and that the datetime formats match up perfectly. FWIW, I also made a webapp (linked in the article) for anybody that didn't want to go through uploading and re-downloading through Google: http://icw.n8henrie.com/

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to do this with Google Calendar

1. Go to Google Calendar "Settings".
2. Import the CSV then Export.
3. As the exported files are split by calendars, you can get the ics file of the imported CSV.